# Is there a function in SageMath that is equivalent to Mathematica's FunctionExpand?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sage

When using the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) with Mathematica, my input and output is:

```
PolyGamma[0,1/5]

PolyGamma[0,1/5]
```

However, if I use:

```
FunctionExpand[PolyGamma[0,1/5]]
```

I get:

```
-EulerGamma-1/8 Sqrt[5/(5/8-Sqrt[5]/8)] \[Pi]-\[Pi]/(8 Sqrt[5/8-Sqrt[5]/8])-Log[10]+1/4 Sqrt[5] Log[5/8-Sqrt[5]/8]-1/4 Sqrt[5] Log[5/8+Sqrt[5]/8]-1/4 Log[(5/8-Sqrt[5]/8) (5/8+Sqrt[5]/8)]
```

Which is what I'm after. Does SageMath have a way to expand a function if it has known constants? If not I suppose I'd have to implement some form of Gauss' digamma theorem.

Not sure if this is the right StackExchange; if not please redirect me to the correct place.

Comment: You can find the definitions here: https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/02/ShowAll.html and here https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/02/0004/

Comment: @axelclk Thank you for the comment. However, I was asking about how to expand it in *SageMath* not Mathematica since I already know how to do that.

Comment: It seems that there is an open ticket for this issue, https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/16652 - so implementing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem may be so far the quick solution, when some few special values of z like 1/5 are the target only.

Comment: @dan_fulea Thanks for the heads up. If you write that up as an answer I'd be glad to close this. Cheers.